# Как в настройках Sublime Text 3 получить имя файла?

Tags: c, python-3.x, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, freepascal

Делаю `.sublime-build`. В другом редакторе, команда сборки выглядит как `fpc %f`. Соответственно Сублайм предостовляет имя файла другой директивой (не `%f`). Вопрос какой?

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "fpc здесь мне надо указать имя файла "
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываем [документацию](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html) и там написано - нужное слово - $file.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "fpc $file"
}
```

Хотя они рекомендуют другой синтаксис

```
{
  "cmd": ["fpc", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "тут регулярка для ошибок"
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.